# KeyCloak on Azure to PostgreSQL "Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints"

Tags: postgresql, azure, keycloak

I am running KeyCloak in an Azure App Service (Docker Container) with the following image "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.1" - just, as it is stated in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker)

My environment variables look like this:
[image]

Everything works fine. I can access KeyCloak with my custom domain and the login to the admin console works too. BUT! One thing does not work: The database.

I am using a PostgreSQL database, which is hosted on Azure as well. I can connect to it with the same credentials as I have entered in the environment variables, with the help of DBeaver (that's where I copied the DB URL from btw).

The logs state the following:

```
2023-03-10T13:54:44.250741391Z 2023-03-10 13:54:44,192 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2023-03-10T13:54:44.253996869Z 2023-03-10 13:54:44,192 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: SSL error: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
2023-03-10T13:54:44.254005969Z 2023-03-10 13:54:44,192 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
2023-03-10T13:54:44.254020670Z 2023-03-10 13:54:44,193 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
2023-03-10T13:54:44.254027270Z 2023-03-10 13:54:44,194 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Algorithm constraints check failed on signature algorithm: SHA1withRSA
```

Just to clarify it: Just to make sure, that the Web App can access the DB I opened it fully (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255). Also, I manually added the "keycloak" schema (which should be the default according to the docs).

Comment: Looks like an issue with your SSL certificates on you postgres. Can you provide the public certificate here?

Comment: Its the default SSL from the Azure PostgreSQL DB. I honestly don't know, how to extract it. As I said: I used basic Azure Resources without any Config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to this [GitHub answer](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17320#issuecomment-1461573077) I was able to track it down.

> It would seem that the Azure Database for Postgresql - Single Server, is using the SHA256 DigiCertGlobalRootG2, for anyone using Single Server would not have this problem.
>
> But for Flexible server, is still using the old SHA1 Root Certificate, causing this error.

Answer (score 6):

workaround for flexible server

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17606#issuecomment-1472289443

> For those who try to solve this one without tempering with security.config to get this working for Azure Flexible PostgresSQL server.
> By adding the certificate from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-tls-ssl
> Into /opt/keycloak/.postgresql/root.crt and setting KC_DB_URL_PROPERTIES="?sslmode=verify-full"

Answer (score 1):

Absolute Final workaround based on all open github threads which works,

Create this DockerFile,

```
FROM alpine/curl:8.1.2 as digicert

WORKDIR /app
RUN curl https://dl.cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem -o DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1
COPY --from=digicert /app/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem /opt/keycloak/.postgresql/root.crt
```

Build the image

```
$ docker build -t mykeycloak .
# docker tag and push image to your registry
# And run anywhere
```

Comment: This answer is based on the GitHub issue: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/17606 with extra docker commands to make it simpler to follow